# Unable to crawl Reddit's NBA page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web crawling and want to learn how to use beautifulsoup to integrate it on a mini project. I was following thenewboston tutorial on beautifulsoup on his [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVNJOiTBi_8) then got stuck trying to crawl off of Reddit. I want to crawl titles and links on each of the NBA news on [Reddit/r/nba](https://www.reddit.com/r/nba/) but didn't have any success. Only thing that return in the terminal was "Process finished with exit code 0". I have a feeling it was to do with my selections? Any guidance and help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the original code, didn't work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://reddit.com/r/nba' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'title'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page += 1

spider(1)
```

I tried doing this way but that didn't solve the problem:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/nba/' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'title'}):
            href = "https://www.reddit.com/" + link.get('href')
            title = link.string
            print(href)
            print(title)
        page += 1

spider(1)
```

Comment: Have you checked what is returned from the requests, you may need to change your user agent string to avoid the bot block.

Comment: It just says "Process finished with exit code 0" when I run the application

Comment: Check what's the value of plain_text. The URL pattern is wrong too.

Comment: Are you building a web crawler because you want the links on the NBA page or because you actually want to get your feet wet building a web crawler? If you just want the links, I recommend using the [Reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api) instead.

Comment: @M.Leung it say I been making too many requests lately and I need to follow the rules

Comment: @supersam654 I want the links and title of the nba news on the NBA page

Answer (score 0):

Get titles and links on main page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("https://www.reddit.com/r/nba/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find('div', {'class':'content'}).find_all('a', {'class':'title may-blank outbound'}):
    print(link.attrs['href'], link.get_text())
```